# Python Multiple inheritance Error:object ha s no attribute

Tags: python

I am new to `python` and asking very basic question. I am trying to understand multiple inheritance. I have two parent classes i.e Speciy and Living and one child class Bird but when i run the  following program, i get error `'Bird' object has no attribute '_Living__house'`.Please tell me what i am doing wrong

But when i use single inheritance i.e class `Bird(Speciy) or class Bird(Living)`it works fine. So only the error comes when i use multiple inheritence

```
class Speciy:

    def __init__(self,legs=4,colour="White"):
        self.__legs=legs
        self.__colour=colour

    def get_legs(self):
        return self.__legs

    def set_legs(self,legs):
        self.__legs=legs

    def get_colour(self):
        return self.__colour

    def set_colour(self,colour):
        self.__colour=colour

class Living:

    def __init__(self,house="city"):
        self.__house=house

    def get_house(self):
        return self.__house

    def set_house(self,house):
        self.__house=house    


class Bird(Speciy,Living):

    def __init__(self,wings=2):
        super().__init__()
        super().__init__()
        self.__wings=wings

    def get_wings(self):
        return self.__wings

    def set_wings(self,wings):
        self.__wings=wings

b1=Bird(4)

print(b1.get_wings())
b1.set_colour("Green")
print(b1.get_colour())
print(b1.get_house())
```

Comment: When i  use only single inheritance then i did not get error, so your comment is not valid

Comment: I have solved the issue my self by replacing class Bird(Speciy,Living) with class Bird(Living,Speciy)

Comment: I think the calls to `super()` should be `super(Speciy, self).__init__()` and `super(Living, self).__init__()`. Works for me.

Comment: @7t7Studios thanks for helping to resolve the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the issue my self using

```
Speciy.__init__(self,legs,colour)
Living.__init__(self,house)
```

Comment: Not working....